# Normal distribution in R (what values for mean and sd?)

Tags: r

I have to make a normal distribution from a set of pre-established data, henceforth *xvec*. So, I know I need to use `dnorm(xvec,meanvec,sdvec)`. But what values I put for *mean* and *sd*? Can I put always `meanvec = mean(xvec)` and `sdvec = sd(xvec)`? Is it a reasonable way? Or is it preferable let the default values of mean=0 and sd=1?

I'm asking this because I looked some examples and the values for mean and sd alwayes were chosen before. For example, this one, from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_normal_distribution.htm:

*Create a sequence of numbers between -10 and 10 incrementing by 0.1.*

x <- seq(-10, 10, by = .1)

*Choose the mean as 2.5 and standard deviation as 0.5.*

y <- dnorm(x, mean = 2.5, sd = 0.5)

Why did he put mean=2.5 and sd=0.5, once 
`> mean(x)`
`[1] 5.105265e-16`
`> sd(x)`
`[1] 5.816786`?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what you want to do with the output.

Comment: The tutorial you quote is setting up a plot from -10 to 10. They are not creating `x` as a random variable, they are creating `x` as an evenly spaced sequence to plot values along. `y` is not the distribution of `x`, `y` is `y` values corresponding to the `x` values for this curve, which happens to be a normal distribution curve. When you say "make a normal distribution from a set of pre-established data", it is probably expected that you use the data, rather than using `mean = 0; sd = 1` which ignores the data.